# The dative case in medieval English

Tags: grammatical-case, old-english

I speak an analytic language, Chinese, and a weakly inflected language, English. As such I'm having a bit of trouble wrapping my head around the concept of the dative case in Old English. I understand its foremost role is to mark the indirect object, but consider the following lines:

```
and forgif ūs ūre gyltas,
swā swā wē forgifaþ ūrum gyltendum
```

I've always thought that "our guilt" in the first line was accusative plural. why, then, do "ure" and "gyltend" have the dative case in the following line?

Thanks.

Comment: I know nothing about medieval English, but I find this very interesting. I assume it is an extract of the Lord's prayer *And forgive us our trespasses; as we forgive those who trespass against us*. So, in modern English *trespass* is being used first as a noun, and then a verb. Does that have anything to do with the change from *gyltas* to *gyltendum*?

Comment: Just realised that whether an object is dative or accusative doesn't depend at all on whether there's another object for the verb nearby. It seems my modern English thinking is creeping in. Apparently, in Old English, whomever you "forgive" takes the dative case, and whatever you "forgive" the person for takes the accusative. "Urum gyltendum" means "those who have trespassed against us", hence the dative plural. For the same reason in the first line, it's "forgif us" rather than *forgif usic.

Comment: You’re right about that. In a strong case system, verbs that take indirect objects like "telling him something" still take the dative for *him* even when the direct object is omitted. There is never a promotion from a dative indirect object to an accusative direct object triggered by omission of the accusative anywhere else. That's because the person of benefit remains unchanged. Even under the analysis of Modern English that some people say this happens in is itself suspect, as beneficiaries are not changed.

Comment: @user3109672 Hope you don't mind, but I've taken out the explanation of your edit as it was  confusing for anyone who hadn't seen the earlier version. (I was trying to work out where you got 'sending men' out of 'forgive those who trespass against us'!).

Comment: The *ūrum gyltendum* is still the indirect object. Just because you don't mention the direct object, doesn't mean the indirect object must take its place now. That wouldn't even make any sense! You always forgive *me*, you always forgive *us*, and you always forgive *ūrum gyltendum*. It is always dative. It does not matter what it is you are forgiving. It does not have to be mentioned anywhere. And this has nothing to do with medieval English, either. That is the case in contemporary Germanic languages as well, and in contemporary Slavic languages, and in Latin and in Ancient Greek.